Display hierarchical relation on Excel or Power Bi
I'm trying to find a way to sort a hierarchy in Power Bi or Excel.
I would like to find a way to keep the (visual) structure in order. Keep the nesting between each parent and each child.
Here is the order I want to keep in Power Bi or Excel :

Here is what i got actually in Excel (not filtered, only the original file order. And as you can see, this in no way reflects the actual structure of the product. The levels are jumbled up and not consistent with each other... ) :

I tried to add a new 'sorted_order' column and add something alphabetic but no success.
Something like A AA AB AC ACA ACB ACD AD ADA But it's obviously not the best way to do this.
So if you guys have an idea ... I work on Python.
Thanks for you help
